# Stop Eclipse/Subversive from setting svn:mime-type to text/plain on initial commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, mime-types, subversive

How do I stop Subversive from setting `svn:mime-type` to `text/plain` on initial commit?

My Java code is being checked into my repository with the `svn:mime-type` property set as `text/plain`, and as a result my web-based SVN viewer (trac) isn't syntax highlighting.

I should add I'm running Eclipse 3.5 and the most recent version of Subversive with the SVNKit 1.3.0 (for SVN 1.6) adapter.

---

**For those finding this question, this issue no longer exists as it was [resolved](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322772) through an option in the preferences section of Subversive.**

Comment: I have no earthy idea.  I had this exact question, and it was really helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to actually setup the mime types yourself in "Window > Preferences> Team > SVN > Properties Configuration > Automatic Properties"

For file type *.java for example, set it to:
svn:mime-type=text/x-java

Answer (score 3):

If your project already got messed by subversive, cd to project root and run the following commands

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec svn propset svn:mime-type 'text/x-java' {} \;
find . -name "*.xml" -exec svn propset svn:mime-type 'text/xml' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Subversion only sets **svn:mime-type** to **application/octet-stream** when the file is binary (and you didn't explictly assign any other value). See [Automatic Property Setting](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto) for reference. So this feature is courtesy of Subversive.

I'm afraid I'm not a Subversive user, but I found in Google a reference to a menu in "Window > Preferences> Team > SVN > Properties Configuration > Automatic Properties" where it seems you can remove unwanted associations.

Comment: There are no associations in the list -- which is why this is confusing

Comment: Then check the places where Subversion itself takes this setting. They're mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Trouble is, like you said, SVN by default *only sets* svn:mime-type for binary files, all others the property should not be set. (and I'm using the SVNKit 1.3.0 connector)

Answer (score 1):

We just ran into this as well. FYI all, I've posted https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322772

Comment: Thanks for creating an Eclipse bug, I resigned to the fact there was nothing I could do.

Answer (score 0):

The reported bug by vorburger (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322772) has been fixed. There is an option called 'Set text MIME type for all non-binary files' under "Window > Preferences> Team > SVN > Properties Configuration > Automatic Properties" which needs to be unchecked to prevent Subversive to add the S/MIME-Type to newly added resources.