# Configure mime-types in Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

To have browsable javadocs in a project hosted at Google-code, I got from [here](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2007/11/09/howto-publish-javadoc-on-google-code/) the recipe: set the correct **mime-type** property (text/html) when Subversion commits HTML pages.

Does anyone knows how to configure that in **Subclipse**?

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049743/stop-eclipse-subversive-from-setting-svnmime-type-to-text-plain-on-initial-commi) gives the pointer to do it in **Subversive** (there is a Preference tab for that). I couldn't find anything similar for Subclipse.

Someone comments about doing a `Team->SetProperty` for the whole javadocs dir (recursively), but that is not extension specific (I'd want `text/css` for stylesheets, for example); and further, I guess, if when new files are created I must remember to do it again...

Is there an alternative?

*Update (2001-06-11):* In case somebody is interested: I couldn't find a way to accomplish this, so I ended switching to Subversive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure the MIME types information, edit the following file:
Windows 7/Vista: **C:\Users[YOUR_USER]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config**

In the config file, locate the property enable-auto-props and uncomment it. It should be set to yes. Make sure there is no space at the beginning of the line:

enable-auto-props = yes

The last section will be [auto-props] and by default everything will be commented out. Add your required file type with the appropriate config.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do part of the work in the shell, by setting mime-type via script.