# Why not doesn't Google maps view the kml layout?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I do [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml). I copied the source code from here. I use the similar .kml file too!

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696, -87.624207);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                center: chicago,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                url: 'https://de-ik-kml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cta.kml'
            });
            ctaLayer.setMap(map);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

But when I would like to use my url, the google maps doesn't load or view the .kml file. I don't understand why don't.

The Developer tool of Chrome doesn't show any errors. So I can't debug what is the problem. I don't find.
I tried that I replace the '`https`' to '`http`', but this isn't solve my problem.
I just changed only the `url` javascript variable's value in my code.

[Here is my .kml file online](https://de-ik-kml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cta.kml)

Answer (score 0):

Your file from SVN has the wrong content type in the headers:

```
Content-Type:·text/plain
```

See this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/kml-samples/issues/detail?id=426) and [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049743/stop-eclipse-subversive-from-setting-svnmime-type-to-text-plain-on-initial-comm) for more details.

The [mime-type for KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server) needs to be  `application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml`

[This may also be helpful](https://code.google.com/p/foothill-web-gis/source/detail?spec=svn73&r=13)

> Set the mime type of all to be application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml using svn
>   propset svn:mime-type 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml' *.kml (thanks to
>   http://manjeetdahiya.com/2010/09/29/serving-html-documentation-from-google-code-
>   svn/ for the tip).