# Is there a verbose errors setting on Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having an issue with Google Maps not displaying my program generated KML file (see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26933638/2535)). My question is if there is a way to turn on more verbose errors so I can see if there is an error with my program generated KML file or if there is a different issue.

Comment: See my answer. KML layer has a getStatus method to find out why isn't it working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933638/program-generated-kml-file-validates-but-doesnt-work/26976214#26976214

Comment: @amenadiel Make a simple answer here about `getStatus()` and I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for KML layers, set a listener for the status_changed event and display the layer's status:

```
var newKml = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ 
    url: VALID_KML_URL_HERE
});
newKml.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(newKml, 'status_changed', function () {
    console.log('KML status is', newKml.getStatus());
});
```