# Traffic Camera KML link address from FTP

Tags: kml

A free KML link on CA traffic camera is working on my dashboard, (http://quickmap.dot.ca.gov/data/cctv.kml), but when I save the file into my FTP server and create a new link, the link is dead. (http://imodelicon.com/pinkertan/trafficcamera/California%20Traffic%20Camera.kml)

Does anyone know why and how to fix the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why not doesn't Google maps view the kml layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501713/why-not-doesnt-google-maps-view-the-kml-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is serving the KML with the wrong "Content-Type": `Content-Type:    text/plain`

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server), that should be:

- `application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml`